# Is it possible to write cross-platform LLVM IR for `feof(stdin)`?

Tags: cross-platform, stdin, llvm-ir

I'm working on a compiler for my programming language using LLVM, and one function checks whether stdin is closed without reading from it. In C, this is a simple `feof(stdin)`. However, `stdin` is a macro that varies from platform to platform. On Windows, it becomes a runtime call to `__acrt_iob_func`; on (some?) Linux, it's an external pointer; and I can't find any information on what the macro expands to on BSDs.

I already have to write two versions of some functions, since it appears that Windows applies C++ name mangling to some functions such as `printf`. However, I would like to write as few OS-specific definitions as possible. Is there an OS-independent equivalent of `feof(stdin)`?